# Запятая в оборотах с "при"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении?

"При использовании поставщиков из разных стран(,) это обеспечивает очень быструю комплектацию заказов".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь запятая не нужна. Она может ставиться, если оборот слишком распространен, просто чтобы отметить его конец.

ЗЫ Интересно, модератор Виталина так теперь и будет править каждый пост? Экий редактор пропадает...

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Это я там большую букву забыла. )))